# How to overcome SSL Certificate with Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, automated-tests, ssl-certificate

I have to write tests which use a local page, normally we write tests on Stage. it is like:

```
webDriver.get("https://abc.local");
```

I have already added the certificate on Firefox. I have also set it in Firefox > Preferences > Security > Exceptions ... to add this page as an exception. But when I run the test, it's always stopped by certificate, so I can't open the page.

Is there anyway webDriver can bypass or suppress this certificate exception? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try and check guru99's guide on how to handle SSL cert error in Firefox:

http://www.guru99.com/ssl-certificate-error-handling-selenium.html#7

Basically, you can - when starting the Firefox webdriver - state that untrusted certificates are allowed so you wont get the error.

Comment: thanks, I followed guru99 explanation, and it works!